# Decrypting opened textfile with unknown key using ASCII in C Caesar Cipher

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

So I was wondering how I could decrypt an encrypted textfile that is opened through a command line argument using ASCII and with an unknown key and then printing it all out and with the answer key. I seem to have been able to actually print out the encrypted message but don't have a clue on how to determine how to find the key and print it out.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp = stdin;  // defaults
  int  n = 13;
  int shift;
  // process command line
  switch (argc) {
    default:
      fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // should check for problems
      n  = atoi(argv[2]);
      break;
  }
  // rotate text
  int c, key;
  int i;
  while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  // This is where I have managed to make C an integer 
  // and print out the encrypted message using the printf function.
```

Comment: What type of encryption is being used?

Comment: @user3386109 caesar cipher

Comment: So I would suggest reading the file into memory. Then printf a small sample using every possible key, and ask the user which key was correct. After that, you can print the whole file with that key.

Comment: Being a chiper, you can't just "find out" what the key is. You have to try every possible key, and then select the best. Maybe using a dictionary to check whether the key is producing meaningful output.

Comment: Are you trying to crack it? Do you know anything relevant the message should contain?

Comment: @Shomz I have a dictionary file that it reads in the command line arguement

Comment: Then you can just keep rotating the string until you find a common word. If you make a full circle with no results, try another word.

Comment: Are only letters encrypted? Are uppercase letters encrypted as uppercase letters and lowercase letters encrypted as lowercase letters? With the same offset (aka shift)?

Comment: @TomBlodget Yea only the letters are encrypted so uppercase letters are encrypted as uppercase and lowercase letters encrypted as lowercase, however there are symbols too. For example in a document I have to decrypt it has Mjqqt which decrypted would be Hello and then it would print out the key being 5, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Shomz I have a rotate function that rotates c and n but how would I rotate it to find a word? I have c= rotate(c,n)

Comment: After each rotation you need to compare the new string to a common word, `Hello` in the case from the comment above.

Comment: @Shomz Would I do that using a for loop?

Comment: Any loop will work (a for loop is fine), just make sure you cover all rotations.

Comment: @Shomz so would I put the loop before the rotation or in the loop? I'm a little confused. So far I have
          (!isspace(c)){
         c = rotate(c,n);
       }

Comment: I meant when you rotate the whole string (you build another string from a key), then you do the string comparison to see if your new string contains your key word, and you repeat that process until you cover all the rotations (or ideally, until you find your key word).

Comment: @Shomz So you are saying after c = rotate(c,n) it creates a new string? But isn't my c a single ASCII character?

Comment: I'm giving you general guidelines/ideas. Yes, your `c` is a character, I'm talking about expanding your code. Check out some of the existing implementations online.

Comment: @Shomz I realized that I have to loop through my small dictionary file and see if it matches a word. However, since I set n equal to the arguement which would be smalldictionary, how can I set my loop to go through that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, decryption without knowing the key is impossible. Luckily, your message is encrypted with one of the simplest methods possible...
Caesar cipher encryption works like so:
* Choose offset K
* For every letter in message do
** Letter = Letter+K

So if we wanted to break that code, we could just go over all possible values of K (255) and rule out every possibility that generates ASCII codes that are not letters or numbers (assuming the original message is in plain English).

You might still need some user interaction to decide if there is more than one option, but the options will be limited.

Comment: How do I make an offset K?

Comment: The question is about ASCII. So K is at most 127. But since it was explained that only letters are remapped and case is preserved, K is at most 25.